# c# Keep order in concatenated Hebrew strings

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, right-to-left, hebrew

I have three strings, string1 is in Hebrew, string2 is an underscore, and string3 is in Hebrew again.

When I concatenate them using String.Concat(string1, string2, string3), the resulting string is string**3**_string**1** (the two Hebrew strings are inverted). I cannot find a workaround, see screenshot for real example.

Note that I do not know what language the strings are in, so I cannot test and change the concatenation accordingly, and I need them in the order I concatenate them.

Anyone can suggest a solution?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You mean the strings won't always be in Hebrew?

Comment: Correct, both can be in any language. However, I noticed this issue only when *both* are in Hebrew or Arabic (I think any RTL string will behave that way).

Comment: The result string is actually string1_string3, it just prints from right to left.

Comment: You can use the debugger to watch `tableName2[0]` (first char of the string), to see the if the content of the result string is reversed.

Comment: @shingo you are absolutely right! Geeez, I didn't see that one coming :-)
Do you know whether there is a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: @shingo, can you post that as an answer? I'll then mark the question as answered. thanks.

Comment: You can prefix it with a `RTL` character to force the whole thing into RTL, or you can change your language to Hebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result string is actually string1_string3, it just prints from right to left.